# How to transfer select_tag parameter to button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to transfer the :action that user select to the next page

index.html.erb

```
<td><%= select_tag :action, options_for_select(actions[account.type])%>
<%= button_to "execute", {:controller => "records", :action => "new", :type => :action, :account_name => account.name}, class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @record do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :type, value: :type %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :account_name, value: params[:account_name] %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

RecordController

```
class RecordsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @records = Record.all
  end

  def new
    @record = current_user.records.build
  end

  def create
    @record = current_user.records.build(create_params)
    if @record.save
        flash[:success] = "Posted successfully"
        redirect_to('/root/tally_book')
    else
        redirect_to('/root/tally_book')
    end
end

def destroy
    @record = current_user.records.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @record && @record.destroy
        flash[:success] = "Post deleted"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Cannot delete post"
    end
        redirect_to('/root/tally_book')
end

private

def create_params
    params.require(:record).permit(:account_name, :description, :usage, :type, :sum, :receipt)
end
end
```

The account_name be sent successfully

But the type is become word 'type' instead of user selected

How to transfer the :type user selected?

Comment: wrap it up with a form and just use submit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to transfer the `action` selected option in the index as the `type` on the new form ?

*index.html.erb*

```
<td>
  <%= form_for(new_record_path(account_name: account.name), class: "btn btn-primary") do |f| %>
  # Not sure you need to specify method: :get, as it is already defined in your routes when you wrote `resources: :records`
  <%= select_tag :action, options_for_select(actions[account.type]) %>
  <%= submit_tag "execute", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

*Then in your new.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for @record do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :type, value: params[:action] %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :account_name, value: params[:account_name] %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Or, you can actually do this stuff in your controller

```
def new
  @type = params[:action] ? params[:action] : DEFAULT_VALUE
end

and use `<%= f.hidden_field :type, value: @type %>`
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

But the account_name is not transfer to the 'new' page 

Finally, I use following method 

    <td><%= form_tag(new_record_path, method: 'get') do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :account_name, account.name %>
    <%= select_tag :type, options_for_select(actions[account.type]) %>
    <%= submit_tag "執行動作", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %></td>

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<%= form_tag(new_record_path(account_name: account.name), method: 'get' do %>
  <%= select_tag "action", options_for_select(actions[account.type]) %>
  <%= submit_tag "execute", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```